# How to force a compilation and ignore @typescript-eslint errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm currently working on a React project, initiated with Create React App. Currently, to compile, I am using the default command `npm run start` which runs `react-scripts start`.

I have a bunch of `@typescript-eslint` rules that force me to have a clean code before delivering it and deploy it. However, while I'm developing, I may have some unused variables and still want to compile to see if something else works.

Is there a command to force the compilation, while ignoring some or all `@typescript-eslint` rules?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a CRA configuration that can be overwritten. In an `.env` file, you can add these variables

```
TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
```

Here is the full list https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Comment: Thanks! Using your solution, actually created a command in my package.json instead of creating a .env file: `"force-start": "TSX_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true react-scripts start"`

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen Yep, no problem. As a side note, it'd probably be good to have an `.env` file for other configurations as well (prod, dev, and maybe staging). Good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: That will come when I'll have a production project (especially with Docker), for now I'm just trying to set the cleanest environment to work with React + TypeScript, thanks!